# Self.view.frame.size.width incorrect on iPhone 6

Tags: ios

Currently have an app that was upgraded to iOS 9 and it has a launch screen file and launch images assigned in the asset. When using the following is getting 320 instead of the correct width for iphone 6.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setUIDefaults];

    [self.cvDash registerClass:[DashEventsNewsCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DashCell"];
    [self.cvDash registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"WebCell"];
    self.cvDash.delegate = self;
    self.cvDash.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
    lastIndex = 0;

    self.vDashboardHeader.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"View Width:%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Bounds Width:%f",self.view.bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Main Screen Width:%f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
}


2016-03-08 17:14:16.069 iSOMobile[78233:5738734] View Width:320.000000
2016-03-08 17:14:17.150 iSOMobile[78233:5738734] Bounds Width:320.000000
2016-03-08 17:14:17.783 iSOMobile[78233:5738734] Main Screen Width:375.000000
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The view hasn't been laid out yet in `viewDidLoad`, so it won't have its final size.

Comment: @dan Where do you recommend doing this?

Comment: Well you never said what you were doing so.. I dunno?

Comment: @dan Adding a view programatically and want it to have the same width as the superview.

Comment: Give it width equal to the current width and either set constraints or give it an autoresizing mask so it resizes when the superview does

Comment: You can check the width in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, but frankly if you use auto layout (or auto resizing masks), you don't have to worry about `width` at all. We can probably advise you better if you explain how/why you're using `width`...

Comment: Im creating subviews programatically and setting the width of the subviews to the self.frame.width

Comment: Sure, you can create views programmatically, but you can configure them using constraints, and then you don't care what the width is. We'd be happy to show you, but you haven't provided any code that creates any subviews, so it's hard for us to know what sort of demonstration would be most illuminating in your example. If you can't show us screen snapshot, describe the nature of the subviews.